# How do I use the ExecuteQuery method properly?

Tags: c#, linq

How do I use the method ExecuteQuery properly?

I get the following information when trying to save an edit.

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A query parameter cannot be of type '<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.String,System.Int32]'.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

    public ActionResult UpdateRegion()
    {
        AtlasDataContext db = new AtlasDataContext();

        var CurrRegionName = Request.Form["RegionName"];
        var CurrRegionID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["RegionID"]);

        string UpdateQuery = "update Regions set RegionName = '"+CurrRegionName+"' where RegionID = "+CurrRegionID+"";

        db.ExecuteQuery<string>(UpdateQuery, new { CurrRegionName, CurrRegionID });

        return RedirectToAction("Admin");
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109(v=vs.110).aspx), the `ExecuteQuery` method expects two parameters - the first is the query itself, and the second is an `object[]` containing the parameters. However, instead of passing an *array*, you're passing an anonymous object containing two properties. The way to pass an array would be this:

```
db.ExecuteQuery<string>(UpdateQuery, new object[] {CurrRegionName, CurrRegionId});
```

**However**

This is not the main problem with your code. The problem is that you're not actually passing a parametrized query to the DB. When you're constructing your query, you're using string concatenization to create the SQL, and you're embedding the parameter values in the string itself, which is a huge security risk, and misses the point of parameterizing the query.

As you can see in the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109(v=vs.110).aspx), your code should be:

```
 string UpdateQuery = "update Regions set RegionName = {0} where RegionID = {1}";
 db.ExecuteQuery<string>(UpdateQuery, new object[] { CurrRegionName, CurrRegionID });
```

Comment: Thank you _soo_ much. I've been beating my head against a wall all week. Saw the documentation previously but had a little trouble reading it, I'm new to c#.  You're a life saver.

Comment: The syntax for array initialization and object initialization are very similar and can be confusing if you're not used to it.

Comment: The `ExecuteQuery` method takes a list of objects as a `param` parameter, so passing it a single object is fine

Comment: @AurelienGasser it's fine in the sense that it compiles and runs, not in the sense that it does what the OP expected it to.